# Boto3: Verify if the file has been uploaded using upload_file()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm making a backup script using boto3 using this line to upload the item:

```
bucket.upload_file(backup_file_name,bucket_path+backup_file_name)
```

How can I verify if this file has really been uploaded to my bucket? I tried to find something using boto3 doc but I didn't found anything. Does this method throws any exception that I can handle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will raise `boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError`. You can also do a [`head_object`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) request to verify that the object looks like it should. This will raise a `botocore.ClientError` with the code `404` if the object does not exist.

Comment: I just checked the [exceptions file](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/exceptions.py) but the 'S3UploadFailedError' seems to be empty, it's just a Boto3Error subclass without implementation... I'm new with python so I may have misunderstood this. However i'll try using head_object

Comment: @Chittolina it's the exception that will be raised if the transfer fails. See the source [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/s3/transfer.py#L379). If you don't trust clean return, then head_object is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is few ways to check. First, you should always make sha256 hash for your file. When you upload, remember to put this info inside the Meta part of the object upload script.

- read the whole file, retrieve the sha256 has from the header meta, and recalculate the has to check it is tally.
- Add an events for the bucket on PUT. When file successfully uploaded, send the events to a queue which you can inspect.  So in success upload but your program crash afterwards, you still have a fall back than reupload the file again.