# How to Check status of S3 upload using boto3 in Python

Tags: python, boto3

Here is my code for upload a file to S3 bucket sing boto3 in python.

```
import boto3

def upload_to_s3(backupFile, s3Bucket, bucket_directory, file_format):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(backupFile, s3Bucket, bucket_directory.format(file_format))

upload_to_s3('/tmp/backup.py', 'bsfbackup', 'pfsense/{}', 'hello.py')
```

My question is about, I want to print the "Upload success" once the upload is succeeded, and print "Upload is failed" and the error stack if the uploading is failed.
Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Start by adding a `try` / `except` block.

Comment: @KlausD. it works up to some level, but error stack is not printed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boto3: Verify if the file has been uploaded using upload\_file()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580092/boto3-verify-if-the-file-has-been-uploaded-using-upload-file)

Comment: @runnerpaul, I'm confused about applying it to my code.

Comment: In the `except` section you can either re-raise the exception with a simple `raise` or use the [traceback module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to print the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
except ClientError as e:
   logging.error(e)
   return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

to upload, u can use this alternative also,

The callback will give u the status of how many bytes of data has been transfer

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
import threading 

def upload(file, input):
    transfer = S3Transfer(s3)
    size = float(os.path.getsize(file))
    transfer.upload_file(**input,
                         callback=_progress(file, size, 'Upload'))

def _progress(filename, size, ops):
    """ indicator to calculate progress based on filesize
    """
    _filename = filename
    _size = size
    _seen_so_far = 0
    _ops = ops
    _lock = threading.Lock()

    def call(bytes_amount):
        with _lock:
            nonlocal _seen_so_far
            _seen_so_far += bytes_amount
            percentage = (_seen_so_far / _size) * 100
            logging.info(
                "%s: %s  %s / %s  (%.2f%%)" % (
                    _ops, _filename, _seen_so_far, _size,
                    percentage))

    return call
```